# How do I write a POST variable to a text file within SharePoint 2010

Tags: ajax, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, fwrite

I’m working on a project that uses SharePoint 2010. I need to write a POST variable to a file using an ajax call.

If I were using PHP I would use the fwrite() function to write the POST to a file.

Here is how I envision my solution working. When you go to notarealwebsite.com and submit the form, I envision using an ajax call to write the file. The ajax on the index.php would look like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'save-text.php',
    data: {json: JSON.stringify(strJson)}
});
```

In PHP I would pass the POST variable into the save-text.php file and its code would look like this:

```
<? php
$file = fopen("file.txt","w");
fwrite($file, $_POST['json']);
fclose($file);
?>
```

Does SharePoint have an equivalent function I can use to save the POST to a file?

Comment: If you are developing a custom web part in a non-sandboxed environment, you can do something similar to PHP.

Comment: OK, I can try this. It is a non-sandboxed environment.

Comment: I've updated the question and added some example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't give us too much here...

You can develop something in JavaScript using a third library like [SharepointPlus](http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/) with the [createFile function](https://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/files.html#createFile)

You'll do:

```
$SP().createFile({
  content: JSON.stringify(strJson),
  destination: "http://mysite/Shared Documents/file.txt",
  url:"http://mysite/",
  after:function() {
    alert("File saved");
  }
});
```

The `createFile` of SharepointPlus uses the [CopyIntoItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/copy.copy.copyintoitems.aspx) web service of Sharepoint.

Comment: I added a level of detail hoping to clarify my question for you. Thanks for responding.

Comment: So my answer is still valid. I've just added an example.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint environment, you would most probably write these strings to list instead of file system. This is especially true if its some kind of configuration value because you want it accessible from all the frond end machines. A file on a filesystem will be created on just a single node where the code runs ultimately after the load balancer.

See: 
How to: Create, Update, and Delete List Items
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee539976(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee539976%28v=office.14%29.aspx)